# Transformer symmetry

Tags: transformer

Thinking of using a Murata 78602/3C, which is a 1:1:1 pulse transformer. Described as two primaries and a secondary. My question is whether these terms for primary and secondary are arbitrary given it's 1:1:1. Can any winding be used like any other?

Comment: I am assuming current carrying capacity is the same for all three windings (or is irrelevant to my use).

Comment: I think that the magnetic coupling between two secondary windings might be worse in some ways, moreover I think that some parameters, i.e. the inductance, are not well controlled while in the primary they are. That's just a couple of ideas, I might totally be wrong.

Comment: Since this is actually a toroidal transformer, cooling of primary and secondaries are different as well as primary rush curent aparameters and electrical isolation between windings are not the same. So I don't recommend to use a secondary as primer in every application. Manufacturer also distinuish the pinout

Comment: In a more general sense, can (say) a 10:1 transformer be used in reverse as a 1:10?

Answer (score 1):

> Can any winding be used like any other?

My very strong suspicion is that the 1kV isolation rating applies between primary and either of the two secondaries. This should not be taken to mean that 1kV isolation is between the two secondaries. Almost certainly this won't be the case. So, if you are using the transformer as an isolator I would say that "any winding" **cannot** "be used like any other".

Comment: Looking further at the spec sheet: 

"This series has toroidal isolation transformers, with no additional insulation between primary and secondary windings of enameled wire."

Comment: @DirkBruere The norm with data sheets is that if there was a feature that could be exploited they'd mention it. In the absence of anything you should not assume isolation of 1kV exists between the two secondaries.

Comment: I'm not too worried about isolation. The maximum voltage across any winding at present is around 30Vpp. It *might* be as high as 100Vpp at a later date depending on design changes but that is still only 10% of rated max. At present I am just breadboarding stuff.

Comment: @D - try it out then and see what happens but, if you are looking to depend on secondary-secondary voltage withstand you'll need to contact the supplier.

Comment: OK - thanks. If I have to go to a significant voltage, and I have to use this xformer then I'll contact them and post here. Right now it's still experimental, and as you might have guessed I don't like transformers!